# Apache Camel XMPP:I am trying to hit a URI using XMPP protocol using recipientList component of apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, xmpp

Here is the exception stack trace when I am hitting the URI using recipientList.
I am using Camel XML DSL.

```
recipientList
    <simple>xmpp://admin@domain.myorg.net:5222?password=XXXXX</simple>
/recipientList>
```

> **Exception** org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateProducerException: Failed to create Producer for endpoint:
>   Endpoint[xmpp://admin@domain.myorg.net:5222?password=xxxxxx]. Reason:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target.

Let me know if any other details is required

Answer (score 1):

This error can for example happen if you want to connect to an SSL endpoint, but you don't trust the endpoint certificate.

So either you don't provide a truststore at all or the endpoint uses a self-signed certificate and you don't have that in your truststore.

If you google for the error message `unable to find valid certification path to requested target` you will find loads of information about it.